# Populate an array to consist of all of the values in an html select list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML select list (let's call it List A) that is dynamically populated with a list of values.  I need to change another select list (List B) depending on the value of List A.  That part, I can do.  Ordinarily, the user selects *one* element of List A, and gets a List B contingent on List A.

However, the first element of List A is "All Values."  Therefore, in this instance, I want a List B that consists of the aggregate of all of the values possible for List B.  Because the available values of List A are dynamically generated, I can't simply pull all List B values.  I need to pull all List B values contingent on all List A values *shown*.

To do this, I want to iterate through all of the values in List A, and append to List B for each item in List A.  This is where I'm stuck.  **How can I populate an array to consist of all of the values in a select list?**  Again, because List A is populated dynamically, the only way to get a list of these values is to pull them from the select list element.

I tried this:

```
iterate_models = $.map($('#listA'), function(e) { return $(e).val(); });
```

This did not give me an array of the values of each element in #listA.  I can't figure out why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map `val()` over all the `<option>` elements in your dropdown list:

```
iterate_models = $.map($("#listA option"), function(e) {
    return $(e).val();
});
```

Comment: Furthermore, you'll probably want to exclude the "All Values" option (e.g. set that option to `value="0"` and inside your `.map()` anonymous function put `if ($(e).val() != 0) return $(e).val();`

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem here is that your selector will select the actual `select` element and get it's `value`. You want ***all*** the values of the `option` elements inside that `select`. Your selector should therefore be, `#listA > option`. You need to chain a `.get()` call on the `$.map()` call because the return value of `$.map()` is a *jQuery-wrapped* array, and you want a basic array, without the jQuery bells and whistles. Also, you can clean up your code by using the `.map()` variant because you are using map on a jQuery object.

Putting that all together:

```
var optVals = $("#listA > option").map(function() {
                return this.value;
}).get();
$.each(optVals, function(i, val) {
    alert(val);
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcjgb/4/)